# To authenticate message coming from gps coordinates

Tags: encryption, gps, hmac

I want to authenticate that particular message or packet is coming from an genuine gps device( ie it is not send as fake packet from an attacker). I use http for server communication in order to minimize the overhead of server. I searched for many message authentication codes but I do not know what to take as parameter for authentication codes relevant to gps device.The need is that authentication with minimum overhead.